# Unable to access internet within "R" on cmd behind proxy

Tags: r, bash, proxy, rstudio

I have been using R on commandline (BASH). I am unable to access the internet (download any packages). I have tried proxy system wide, and tested it with wget, which works. The "install.packages()" command however does not.

Per some user's advice, I also tried setting the proxy in .Rprofiles file. That didn't help either. Please advice.

Comment: Other than checking to make sure the computer firewall is not targeting connection attempts by unrecognized applications, I fear that this is in the hands of your network administrators. We don't know your network or its settings (nor should we!). Lacking more information, it'd be just speculation.

Comment: Could you try `library(httr)` then `set_config(use_proxy(url="http://abc.def.ghi.jk", port=XXX, username="YourUsername", password="YourPassword"))`. Install `httr` from the source archive if you don't have it.

Comment: @r2evans i thought so too. but ufw is turned off in our server as we are not directly exposed to the internet; connections are wrapped through a university wide proxy which provides protection.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent tried this, did'nt work. undid this, and then for some reason it worked. at the moment i believe it was due to some proxy setting mismatch somewhere. strange.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same issue on my work machine.  Our Firm uses Cylance as its antivirus software.  Cylance was quarantining the file "internet.dll" that R uses to access the Internet.  Fortunately, however, it only does so in the 32-bit version of R.  For me, there were two solutions:

First, I was able to download packages directly from the 32-bit version of R (outside of RStudio).  This works fine.  The downloaded packages will run in 64-bit RStudio.

The longer-term solution was to submit an IT service request to release this file from quarantine (that is, to "whitelist a blocked entity").  At my Firm this was promptly done, as there is (obviously) nothing unsafe about this R file.